# Webpack can't fix CSS override issue and bundle <style> elements in <head>

Tags: css, webpack, webpack-style-loader

In my app, lets say I have two JS pages A and B, and each import a different stylesheet (`import '../style/<A or B.css>'`).
Both stylesheets have identical classnames but but different properties.

I run `yarn run dev ==> dev: webpack-dev-server --inline --hot ==> webpack -p`

This is what my html `<head>` looks like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqpBR.jpg
page A stylesheet is loaded first, then page B css style is loaded after

When I go to Page B, the css is correct
When I go to Page A, the css is mixed up and some class styles are overriden by page B.css.

My project structure is like

```
public/
 bundle.js
 index.html
src/
 components/
 pages/
 style/
 App.js
 index.js
 package.json
 webpack.config.js
```

my webpack.config.js is

```
const path = require('path');

var config = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: [
                { loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: { presets: ['react','env'] } }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                { loader: "style-loader?singleton", 
                  options: 
                  { singleton: true } 
                },
                { loader: "css-loader" }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
};
module.exports = config;
```

I want Webpack to merge the multiple  elements and fix the css override issue
In Webpack, I have tried `style-loader?singleton` and `{ singleton: true }` but it didnt work.

**EDIT 1:** looking into extract-text-webpack-plugin

**EDIT 2:**

```
import movieStyle from '../style/MovieDetail.css' 
... 
return (
<div id="CellDetail_right" className={ movieStyle['cell-detail-right'] }>...</div>
)
```

Ok, I added `options: { modules: true }` and it didnt work. My classNames are hyphenated and after compiling the browser renders the components WITHOUT any style or classes. 
Div on browser looks like `<div id="CellDetail_right">...<div>`

Comment: you can solve this issue setting **css-loader** `modules` option to true

Comment: @Carloluis ok, I did that, now browser renders html without any style or classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to enable local scoped css to avoid styles bleeding/overrides.
Update your `css-loader` options to include `modules: true`

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: "style-loader", 
            options: { singleton: true }
        },
        {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
                modules: true,
                camelCase: 'dashes',
                localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]'
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, using in your components as:

```
import styles from '../style/MovieDetail.css';

function MyComponent() {
    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <div className={styles.cellDetailRight}>Some Content</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This ensures that despite you have more `.container` rules defined in other css files, this particular rule becomes to something like `._-path-to-component__container`.

Using `camelCase: 'dashes'` in options transform your hyphenated rules.

> dashes in class names will be camelized

You can also review my [webpack-demo](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo) project which includes configs to handle your scenario.
Check the [webpack configurations](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo/blob/master/config/webpack.config.dev.js#L45)

Read more on [css-loader options](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#options)

---

[image]

Comment: I did that, now browser renders html without the className attribute. see my comment

Comment: thanks, i got what i wanted. full solution here https://github.com/ridhwaans/homehost/blob/master/client/webpack.config.js

Comment: You're welcome! I checked your webpack style config, and found two rules for `.css` files ([lines 40 and 59](https://github.com/ridhwaans/homehost/blob/master/client/webpack.config.js#L40)). Did was helpful my [webpack-demo](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo) project? Consider also upvoting the answer to show it was helpful..